# Error message after trying to run Emulator on Android Studio: The emulator process for AVD has terminated

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep getting this error message when I try to run a virtual device on Android studio
(for mobile application using Kotlin)

[image: picture of the error]

I've tried some solutions online, but nothing is working.
I've checked the logs, and this is what it gives me

```
2023-04-09 04:21:56,713 [ 503397] SEVERE - Emulator: Nexus 6 API 28 - Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
2023-04-09 04:21:56,713 [ 503397] SEVERE - Emulator: Nexus 6 API 28 - JDK: 11.0.15; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-04-09 04:21:56,713 [ 503397] SEVERE - Emulator: Nexus 6 API 28 - OS: Windows 10
2023-04-09 04:21:57,668 [ 504352]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\lina\.android\avd\Nexus_6_API_28.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Nexus_6_API_28
2023-04-09 04:21:57,669 [ 504353]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\lina\.android\avd\Nexus_6_API_28.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Nexus_6_API_28
2023-04-09 04:21:57,669 [ 504353]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Nexus_6_API_28 is online, assuming it's not
2023-04-09 04:22:02,084 [ 508768]   INFO - #c.i.a.o.PathMacrosImpl - Saved path macros: {}
2023-04-09 04:22:02,139 [ 508823]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appPluginAdvertiserExtensions took 17 ms
2023-04-09 04:22:02,309 [ 508993]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=Dice Roller, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\lina\AndroidStudioProjects\DiceRoller)XDebuggerManager took 18 ms
2023-04-09 04:22:02,370 [ 509054]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jbr
2023-04-09 04:22:31,459 [ 538143]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appCodeInsightSettings took 31 ms, FileTypeManager took 12 ms
2023-04-09 04:22:45,367 [ 552051]   INFO - #c.i.i.a.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
2023-04-09 04:22:46,513 [ 553197]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=Dice Roller, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\lina\AndroidStudioProjects\DiceRoller)KotlinCommonCompilerArguments took 20 ms
```

tried looking up this warning, and the errors I'm getting, but not finding much information, never mind solutions

Things I've tried in the past two days to fix this:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling Android studio
2. Restarting android studio
3. Restarting my computer
4. deleting the device and creating a new one
5. Turned on Hyper-V (Hyper-V Management Tools, Hyper-V Platform) from Windows Feautures
6. Went to settings on android studio, Menus and Toolbars, Navigation Bar Toolbar, Android.SDKUpdates, added an action, and added Virtual device manager
7. Checked for updates for the emulator, (there was an availabe update so I updated)
8. Checked if there was enough space on my disk to run the device (there is more than enough)
9. Tried creating devices with older APIS, or older device versions.
10. Tried adding advancedFeautures.ini file with code:

    ```
    # Here's how to disable Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator.

    # Add the following lines to ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (create this file if it doesn't exist already):

    Vulkan = off
    GLDirectMem = on


    advancedFeatures
    ```
11. Tried to wipe data from the three dots
12. Tried to cold boot
13. Uninstalling and reinstalling the emulator, restarting android studio, and creating a new device and running again

I really don't know what more I can do, and would appreciate any help you guys can offer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found here was to free up disk space on my Mac.  The emulator can't run if it can't allocate disk space.  This fixed it for me:

https://youtu.be/L-Ohw7Yj79s

Comment: I watched this video and tried the things the lady showed. Nothing worked